# Valgrind says I have an uninitialised value right after I initialise it

Tags: c, valgrind

Maybe the answer is obvious or maybe Valgrind is wrong, but I have a memory leak and I was able to isolate this piece of code that gives the same error I'm getting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *values = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    values[i] = i;
  }
  printf("values: %d %d %d\n", values[0], values[1], values[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

The error Valgrind reports is:

```
==2354== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2354==    at 0x1003FCC3F: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Haswell (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==2354==    by 0x1001F0BB6: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==2354==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==2354==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==2354==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==2354==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==2354==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==2354==    by 0x100000F45: main (example.c:12)
==2354==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2354==    at 0x1001F6C18: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
```

And I can't figure out how the print is printing an uninitialised value. What I'm missing?

Comment: how you use valgrind. Paste that command also

Comment: `values` may get NULL. That's probably what it complains about.

Comment: It doesn't complain about your code, it complains about `printf` implementation. Your code just happens to be in the call stack.

Comment: @n.m.: That sounds right. It could be tested by trying something like `printf("values: %d %d %d\n", 0, 1, 2);` (without optimization, so it actually calls `printf`).

Comment: @n.m. You are right, I did a printf with no variables and it reports the same error, thanks, it was driving me crazy, now off to find the actual memory leak in my program.

@Mr.32: `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./example`